# PSQL режет слова в to_tsvector

Tags: postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

PSQL отрезает концовки некоторых слов в to_tsvector.

У меня есть леммы, я хочу искать по ним:

1. кот сделать дело (id: 28)
2. дело сделать кот наконец то (id: 29)

но запрос

```
SELECT id
FROM pst
WHERE to_tsvector("title") @@ plainto_tsquery('наконец')
ORDER BY ts_rank(to_tsvector("title"), plainto_tsquery('наконец')) DESC;
```

ничего не отдает. Как я выяснил:

```
SELECT to_tsvector("title") 
FROM pst 
WHERE pst.id = 28;
-----
'дел':3 'кот':1 'сдела':2
-----
SELECT to_tsvector("title") 
FROM pst post
WHERE post.id = 29;
-----
'дел':1 'кот':3 'сдела':2
```

psql отрезает концовки слов.

Я пробовал поставить в to_tsvector поставить как regconfig другой язык, но в этом случае не работал поиск через ts_query. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: Ть изменяемая часть слова поэтому отброшенна